# Подсветка текста караоке PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

Разрабатываю караоке плеер на *Python*. Для `GUI` использую библиотеку *PyQt5*. Получаю текст из `lrc` файла. Теперь возникла задача красиво подсвечивать слова, как в настоящем караоке по таймингу.

Можете подсказать, что можно использовать для этого? Пытался рисовать прямоугольник сзади, рассчитывая скорость до следующей строчки, но такое решение получается не очень.

Хочется, чтобы именно текст закрашивался. Пример на картинке.

[image: пример]

Answer (score 1):

Я слабо разбираюсь в караоке, но один вариант подсветки текста нарисую.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyHighlighter(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyHighlighter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 150)

    def song(self, listText, ind=0): 
        self.setText(listText[ind])    
        cursor = self.textCursor()

        # Установите желаемый формат 
        # Класс QTextCharFormat предоставляет информацию о форматировании символов в QTextDocument.
        format = QTextCharFormat()
        format.setTextOutline(QPen(QColor("red")))
        format.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold)) 

        # Обработать отображаемый документ
        index = 0
        wordList = self.toPlainText().split()
        for i in wordList:
            cursor.setPosition(index)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord, 1)
            cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
            index = index + len(i) + 1

            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            QThread.msleep(700)

        ind += 1
        if ind < len(listText):
            self.song(listText, ind)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, listText):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textEdit = MyHighlighter()
        btn = QPushButton("Подсветка текста караоке")
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, listText=listText: self.textEdit.song(listText))

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.grid.addWidget(btn)


listText = ["""Я люблю тебя, жизнь,
Что само по себе и не ново,
Я люблю тебя, жизнь,
Я люблю тебя снова и снова.""",
"""Вот уж окна зажглись,
Я шагаю с работы устало,
Я люблю тебя, жизнь,
И хочу чтобы лучше ты стала.""",
"""И так далее..."""]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(listText)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]