# PyQt, подчеркнутый текст в QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qplaintextedit, qpalette

Я сделал проверку орфографии текста, который введен в `QPlainTextEdit`.
Проверка работает, но встал вопрос, как пометить слова не прошедшие проверку? Подскажите как быть?

Вот мой код.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from db.notebook_models import NotebookRubrics
from .add_rubrics import Ui_FormAddRubrics
from shutil import copyfile
import os
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import enchant
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

    # Проверка орфографии
    def spellingText(self):
        c = enchant.Dict("ru_RU")
        text = str(self.addRubrics.editTextArea.toPlainText())
        textSplit = text.split()
        for i in range(len(textSplit)):
            word = textSplit[i]
            for elm in ['?', '!', '.', ',', ':', ';']:
                word = word.replace(elm, "")
            if (c.check(word)!=True):
                text = text.replace(word, '<span style="color:#c70000;">' + word + "</span>")
        self.addRubrics.editTextArea.setPlainText(text)
```

---

Вот в

`text = text.replace(word, '<span style="color:#c70000;">' + word + "</span>")`

я пытаюсь слово с ошибкой пометить красным (в идеале бы сделать волнистой красной линией).
Затем текст заменяется в  `QPlainTextEdit`

Подскажите, как это можно сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: Через setHtml наверное проще будет

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendHtml вроде можно добавить html, не вижу sethtml, но можно очистить и вставить новый фрагмент.

```
self.addRubrics.editTextArea.appendHtml('<span style="text-decoration-style: wavy;text-decoration: underline;text-decoration-color:red">ошибка</span> ')
```

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Я просто продемонстрирую пример, который демонстрирует как это может выглядеть.

Текст может быть отформатирован ограниченным способом, 
либо с помощью подсветки синтаксиса (`syntax highlighter`) (см. ниже), 
либо путем добавления текста в формате `html` с помощью `appendHtml()`. 
Хотя `QPlainTextEdit` не поддерживает сложный рендеринг расширенного текста с таблицами 
и плавающими числами, он поддерживает ограниченное форматирование на основе абзацев.

Подсветка синтаксиса `QTextEdit`, `QPlainTextEdit` работает вместе с `QSyntaxHighlighter`. 
Класс `QSyntaxHighlighter` позволяет вам определять правила подсветки синтаксиса, 
и, кроме того, вы можете использовать этот класс для запроса текущего форматирования документа 
или пользовательских данных.

Некоторые примеры подсветки синтаксиса вы можете посмотреть 
здесь [Редактор кода на PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901830/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt5/901880#901880) 
и здесь [Подсветка текста караоке PyQT5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966257/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-pyqt5)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Template(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.editTextArea = QPlainTextEdit()

        self.editTextArea.setPlainText("""Python Qt Подчеркнутый текст в QPlainTextEdit

Я сделал проверку error орфографии текста, который введен в QPlainTextEdit. 
Проверка работает, но встал вопрос, как пометить слова не прошедшие проверку. 
Вот мой код. Подскажите errorкак быть?

Вот в text = text.replace(word, 'Errors' + word + "") я пытаюсь слово с ошибкой пометить красным 
(в идеале бы сделать волнистой красной линией). 
Затем текст заменяется в QPlainTextEdit Подскажите, как это можно сделать. Спасибо!        
Errors  """)

        fixedFont = QFontDatabase.systemFont(QFontDatabase.FixedFont)
        fixedFont.setPointSize(15)
        fixedFont.setBold(True)
        self.editTextArea.setFont(fixedFont)

        self.button  = QPushButton("Сделать проверку орфографии текста.")        
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.spellingText)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.editTextArea) 
        grid.addWidget(self.button)


    # Проверка орфографии
    def spellingText(self):
        text = str(self.editTextArea.toPlainText())
        for elm in ['?', '!', '.', ',', ':', ';']:                    # ?
            text = text.replace(elm, "")

        text = text.replace('\n', "<br>")                             # +

        errs = ['error', 'Errors', '...',]                            # какие-то слова с ошибками
        for err in errs:
            text = text.replace(err, f'<span style="color:#c70000;">{err}</span>')

        self.editTextArea.clear()                                     # + 
        self.editTextArea.appendHtml(text)                            # + appendHtml


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # палитра для переключения на темные цвета:
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.blue)                            # Qt.white
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)

    gui = Template()
    gui.resize(950, 350)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]